# I am getting "not NULL Constraint error" in my unit test only

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need help. My registration system is working perfectly fine when I run on a local server, but when I run my test. It fails. I don't understand why?
I am unable to figure out what is wrong, I have deleted the entire database and migrations. even I created the new app and did everything there. But still, I am getting this error.

**My test_setup.py**

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.urls import reverse

class TestSetup(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.register_url = '/register/'
        self.user_data = {"Username":"frontend123", "First name":"Frontend", "Last 
                           name":"Developer", "Password":"bitspro##1", "Confirm 
                           password":"bitspro##1","Email":"rida@bitspro.com","Date of 
                           birth":"1997-12-27"}

        return super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        return super().tearDown()
```

**My testViews.py**

```
from authentication.models import User
from authentication.tests.test_setup import TestSetup


class TestViews(TestSetup):

    def test_user_cannot_register_without_any_data(self):
        res = self.client.post(self.register_url)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 400)

    def test_user_can_register_correctly(self):
        res = self.client.post(self.register_url, self.user_data, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
```

**My view.py (I am testing registration system only**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from authentication.models import User as Client
class Register(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('Username')
        first_name = request.data.get('First name')
        last_name = request.data.get('Last name')
        password = request.data.get('Password')
        confirm_password = request.data.get('Confirm password')
        date_of_birth = request.data.get('Date of birth')
        email = request.data.get('Email')
        if password == confirm_password:
            if Client.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
                return Response({"message": "this username already exist"}, 400)
            elif Client.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
                return Response({"message": "This email-address is already taken"}, 400)
            else:
                user= Client.objects.create(username = username, password =password, email=email, 
                                            date_of_birth=date_of_birth)
                user.save()
                return Response({"message":"User has been created"}, 201)
        else:
            return Response({"message": "Try it again"}, 404)
```

**my urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from authentication.views import Login, Logout, Register, Password_Reset

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', Register.as_view(), name = "register"),
]
```

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser



class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    date_of_birth= models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of Birth", max_length=10)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I would really appreciate your help

**my error**

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\garments> python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_user_cannot_register_without_any_data (authentication.tests.test_views.TestViews)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: authentication_user.password

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\garments\authentication\tests\test_views.py", line 8, in test_user_cannot_register_without_any_data
    res = self.client.post(self.register_url)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 295, in post
    response = super().post(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 209, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 233, in generic
    return super().generic(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 473, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 285, in request
    return super().request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 237, in request
    request = super().request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 719, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 580, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\garments\authentication\views.py", line 38, in post
    user= Client.objects.create(username = username, password =password, email=email, date_of_birth=date_of_birth)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: authentication_user.password

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.083s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'..
```

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. It seems you want to put empty string as `password` in database and this raise error - but it seems it is test which use empty value to test code. SO maybe you need to use some try/except to catch it.

Comment: OR you should test if `password` is not empty before you add to database. ie. `if len(password) > 0 and password == confirm_password:`

Comment: see also Django doc: [password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation)